# ignore one tab from auto reloading in safari using AppleScript

Tags: safari, applescript

I am reloading all safari tabs using apple scripts, I want to ignore one of the opened tab from reloading. Below is my code for reloading the opened tabs.

```
  tell application "Safari"
         repeat
            repeat with i from (count of tabs of window 1) to 1 by -1
               set thisTab to tab i of window 1
               set current tab of window 1 to thisTab
               tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke "r" using {command down}
               end tell
               delay 10
             end repeat
         end repeat
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by index (reload everything but tab 4)

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat
        repeat with i from (count of tabs of window 1) to 1 by -1
            if i is not 4 then
                set thisTab to tab i of window 1
                set current tab of window 1 to thisTab
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke "r" using {command down}
                end tell
                delay 10
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

or by URL (reload every tab whose URL does not contain "myServer")

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat
        repeat with i from (count of tabs of window 1) to 1 by -1
            set thisTab to tab i of window 1
            if URL of thisTab does not contain "myServer" then
                set current tab of window 1 to thisTab
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke "r" using {command down}
                end tell
                delay 10
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```